# how to use firewalld in stateful mode

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, firewalld

I have to setup an stateful firewall on centos8 using firewalld.
I'm new to firewalld but have experience with old style iptables for this purpose.
since it is recommended by Redhat [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/using-and-configuring-firewalld_configuring-and-managing-networking#when-to-use-firewalld-nftables-or-iptables_getting-started-with-firewalld), I prefer to not combine two methods like firewalld and iptables. 
I want to know is there a way to use firewalld in stateful mode? if it is how?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firewalld configures iptables or nftables, and the resulting configuration is stateful (based on connstate status: established, related, untrack, invalid, new).

You can check the actual configuration with `iptables -L -n -v` and `nft list ruleset`.

You can choose which backend you want to use in `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf` with the option `FirewallBackend`. If you want Firewalld to use iptables, you have to set: `FirewallBackend=iptables`

If you want to disable Firewalld to use you standard iptables configurations, you can use:

```bsh
systemctl disable firewalld --now
systemctl mask firewalld
```

Comment: thank you! you helped me a lot.